# How can I turn this XML into a sequence

Tags: xml

I am generating this xml file
However, when it gets uploaded to a server,
it only shows 1 entry and not the entire sequence,

what tags do I need to add and where?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Event xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TestParameter>
    <name>param1</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>
  <TestParameter>
    <name>param2</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>  <TestParameter>
    <name>param1</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>  <TestParameter>
    <name>param2</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>
</Event>
```

I want it so that each group of parameters is in a sequence

I tried this, it didnt work,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Event xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Sequence>
  <TestParameter>
    <name>param1</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>
  <TestParameter>
    <name>param2</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>  
 </Sequence>
 <Sequence>
  <TestParameter>
    <name>param1</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>  
  <TestParameter>
    <name>param2</name>
    <parameter_status>PASS</parameter_status>
    <description>Name</description>
    <text_value>B00F</text_value>
  </TestParameter>
 </Sequence>
</Event>
```

Comment: It is not clear how server parses the xml file. We need to know the XML structure or schema. I mean you cannot add a custom tag like Sequence if the server tries to parse TestParameter elements under Event root.